# how to solve Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I compile my spring Boot project, I got the following error.

### org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.FileUpload.Model.Authorities

and my meven properties are shown below 
[image]

and my pom.xml file is given below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.FileUpload</groupId>
<artifactId>FileUpload</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FileUpload</name>
<description>this is file upload project</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every entity has to have @Id field mapped to primary key DB column. `Authorities` are missing it.

Comment: I added  @Id in to Authorities now show below error                                                  Error executing DDL "create table user (username varchar(255) not null, pass varchar(255), enabled boolean, primary key (username))"

Comment: I have two model class with names user and authorities , know after execute my app authorities table is created but user table is not  created!!

Comment: Open new question for that. Actual problem in this question was answered.

Comment: I solve this problem , I should change the user table name, because this name is reserved in postgres!!

Comment: If you think my answer helped to answer you original question mark it as answered.